# mysql report sql help

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table with data like this. record will have server with total cpu and virtual server with cpu assinged

```
type, cpu
srv1,   10
vsrv11, 2
vsrv12,  3
srv2,   15
vsrv21, 6
vsrv22,  7
vsrv23,  1
```

from the above data, I want to create output like this.

```
server, total cpu, assigned cpu, free cpu
srv1, 10, 5, 5
srv2, 15, 14, 1
```

Can you help me on creating sql query for this report?

---

I have changed my table and data like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `cpuallocation` (
  `servertype` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `servername` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hostname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpu_count` float DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `server_uniq_idx` (`servertype`,`servername`,`hostname`)

insert into cpuallocation values('srv', 'server1', '',16);
insert into cpuallocation values('vir', 'server1', 'host1',5);
insert into cpuallocation values('vir', 'server1', 'host2',2.5);
insert into cpuallocation values('vir', 'server1', 'host3',4.5);
insert into cpuallocation values('srv', 'server2', '',8);
insert into cpuallocation values('vir', 'server2', 'host1',5);
insert into cpuallocation values('vir', 'server2', 'host2',2.5);
insert into cpuallocation values('srv', 'server3', '',24);
insert into cpuallocation values('vir', 'server3', 'host1',12);
insert into cpuallocation values('vir', 'server3', 'host2',2);
insert into cpuallocation values('srv', 'server4', '',12);
```

**Update:**

I created two view, now I getting the result I want.

```
create view v1 as 
select servername, sum(cpu_count) as cpu_allocated 
from cpuallocation where servertype='vir' group by servername;

create view v2 as 
select servername, cpu_count as total_cpu 
from cpuallocation where servertype='srv';

select a.servername, a.total_cpu, b.cpu_allocated 
from v2 as a left join v1 as b on a.servername=b.servername;

+------------+-----------+---------------+
| servername | total_cpu | cpu_allocated |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| server1    |        16 |            12 |
| server2    |         8 |           7.5 |
| server3    |        24 |            14 |
| server4    |        12 |          NULL |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is it possible to create a query with-out creating views?

Comment: Who decided to use such way of storing data?

Comment: you should better create a proper table structure before with fields something like `server_number`,`server_type`, `cpu` and write an adjustment script which moves the data from the existing table to this new table. I hope there is usage of proper database abstraction functions throughout the code. If it feels difficult to do the transfer using pure mysql queries, you may try with the server side language which you are using to help your queries. Once that is done, it will be much easier to write an sql query to produce the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be usable for the original table format

```
select 
  a.type as server,
  a.cpu as total_cpu,
  sum(b.cpu) as assigned_cpu,
  a.cpu-sum(b.cpu) as free_cpu
from cpu as a
left join
  cpu as b on locate(concat('v',a.type), b.type)<>0
where a.type in('srv1', 'srv2')
group by a.type;
```

Your table does not seems have a common natural key, you should assign one

This should useful for the updated schema:

```
select
  cpu1.servername as server,
    cpu1.cpu_count as total_cpu,
    ifnull(sum(cpu2.cpu_count), 0) as assigned_cpu,
    ifnull(cpu1.cpu_count-sum(cpu2.cpu_count),0) as free_cpu
from 
  cpuallocation as cpu1
left join
  cpuallocation as cpu2
  on cpu1.servername=cpu2.servername and cpu2.servertype='vir'
where 
  cpu1.hostname = '' 
group by cpu1.servername;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can map the virtual servers to the real servers (e.g. through a BELONGS_TO function ), you could join the table on itself or use a subselect as below:

> select r.type as server , r.cpu as total, sum(select cpu from tablename v where v.type BELONGS_TO(r.type) ) as assigned, total - assigned as free from tablename r;

For the mapping You could try something like

> v.name like CONCAT('%',r.type,'%')

However the results may not be accurate: 'vsrv111' is ambiguous, it could belong to srv11 or srv1.